# Why can't I play co-op?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

When I try to play co-op in Saints Row: The Third, it says I need to enter a code. However, I have already done this and got my unlockable items like the car, gun and clothing. I have been trying to sort it out, but nothing has worked, can you help?

Answer (score 8):

Sounds you like you got a pre-order bonus, and you've entered the code for that. Did you enter a separate code for an Online Pass? It's possible and pretty likely that they are 2 completely different codes on different pieces of paper in the game box.

I ordered mine after the pre-order bonuses and the game only came with a card with the Online Pass code. The online pass card should look something like this:
[image: Online Pass Card]

Comment: I only got the prof genki code, am I meant to get an online code with the game, because I am not pay 800 Microsoft points to go online, thanks though

Comment: If you bought the game new, yes, it should have the online code with it. If used, then no, it won't come with it.

Comment: Oh, I bought it new and that was the only code I got in it

Comment: @Davidchandler The online pass code is found inside the case of the game, on a paper that looks like the one in Doozer Blake's answer. It might possibly be behind the instruction manual, but it's in the same storage space as the instructions would be.

Comment: Got it, it didnt look like the pics but its all Sorted now, thanks guys :) (The code was on the back of the instructions.)

Comment: Hi David, if Doozer has answered your question, please accept it